# Why my admin doesn't work after adding rest_prepare_post filter?

Tags: filters, wp-admin, hooks, rest-api

When I add a filter to custom get_all_posts API callback, API works, but the admin page for each page is blank. Why?

```
function get_all_posts( $data, $post, $context ) {

    return [
        'id'        => $data->data['id'],
        'date'      => $data->data['date'],
        'date_gmt'  => $data->data['date_gmt'],
        'modified'  => $data->data['modified'],
        'title'     => $data->data['title']['rendered'],
        'content'   => $data->data['content']['rendered'],
        'main_text' => $data->data['main_text'],
        'featured_media_url'   => $data->data['jetpack_featured_media_url'],
        'category'  => get_the_category_by_ID( $data->data['categories'][0] ),
        'link'      => $data->data['link']
    ];
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'get_all_posts', 10, 3 );
```

**EDIT:**
Got this error on the webpage `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')`

[image]

FYI: I added a meta box on the post admin page, the meta box works perfectly without the code above.

My entire code:

```
function main_text_meta_box() {

    add_meta_box(
        'main-text',
        __( 'Main text', 'sitepoint' ),
        'main_text_meta_box_callback',
        'post'
    );
}

function main_text_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    // Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'main_text_nonce', 'main_text_nonce' );

    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_main_text', true );

    echo '<textarea style="width:100%; height:300px;" id="main_text" name="main_text">' . esc_attr( $value ) . '</textarea>';
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'main_text_meta_box' );


function save_main_text_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['main_text_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['main_text_nonce'], 'main_text_nonce' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    }
    else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['main_text'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['main_text'] );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_main_text', $my_data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_main_text_meta_box_data' );

function add_custom_fields() {
    register_rest_field(
         'post', 
         'main_text', //New Field Name in JSON RESPONSEs
         array(
          'get_callback'    => 'get_main_text', // custom function name 
          'update_callback' => null,
          'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_fields' );


function get_main_text ( $post, $field_name, $request ){

        return get_post_meta($post['id'], '_main_text', true);
}
```

Comment: Did you turn on your debugging and look at your error log?

Comment: please see my comments, I added some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new block editor uses the REST API and by modifying the rest response through the `rest_prepare_post` filter you compromise the expected data set. I suspect that's the case here, since you're modifying all the responses for the `post` post type, without any conditional restrictions.

Consider creating your own custom route where you can modify the response to your needs without affecting the core/plugin/app use of the builtin REST API routes.  You could also consider e.g. the `_embed` query parameter to get extra information about the category and the featured image.

Answer (score 0):

late to the party, but had the same problem and couldn't find the answer, but figured it out:

it is not working, cause you corrupted the REST answer, that wordpess is expecting. gutenberg is also using the REST api and the filter in use is also executed in the editor. if you want to edit the response, but only for the front end, you would need to add a condition, to check `backend vs. frontend`
wordpress has the build-in `is_admin()` function to check for that, but this one is not working inside REST requests. but you could still check the REST request origin by its context:

```
function so326688_rest_prepare_post($response, $post, $request)
{
    if ($request['context'] === 'view') { // if not is admin
        //your code goes here and will only execute on view requests. inside admin the request would be 'edit'
    }

    return $response;
}
add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'so326688_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3);
```

other than that, i'd say it's not good practice to overwrite the whole response. but you could add your attributes to it. not really sure, what data you changed in your response but this should do as an example:

```
function so326688_2_rest_prepare_post($response, $post)
{

    if (isset($post)) {
        $response->data['category'] = get_the_category_by_ID($response->data['categories'][0]);
    }
   
    return $response;
}
add_filter('rest_prepare_project', 'so326688_2_rest_prepare_post', 10, 2);
```

but your problem definitely was, that you changed the whole response, so gutenberg was missing some values or couldn't find them in the right place.